# send SignTransaction to contract function using web3 + infura + truffle

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, truffle, infura

contract has an function "addToWhiteList", only owner of the contract can access this function and add user in whitelist.

```
/**
* @dev Adds single address to whitelist.
* @param trusted Address to be added to the whitelist
*/
function addToWhiteList(address trusted) public onlyOwner {
   require(!whitelist[trusted]);
   whitelist[trusted] = true;

   emit UserWhitelist(true);
}
```

I am trying to add the user on whitelist from owner account :

```
// Send Transaction to the Blockchain
function sendTransaction() {
 const functionAbi = Contract.methods.addToWhiteList("0x9DA80947ACf5Fc16299311EdAabc37fF7d201C95").encodeABI()
 console.log(functionAbi);
 var nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount("0x61A44075419C4402f6DE631341d875Ece6A3922e");
 var gasPrice = "2";//or get with web3.eth.gasPrice
 var gasLimit = 3000000;
 var ownerPrivateKey = "0x5c9c7e00edc09d0df072c0de7911026a4ab241aa8a5e9f063fb450ba91fbc360";
 var formatedPrivteKey = ownerPrivateKey.substring(2);
 var tx = new ethereumjs.Tx({
   nonce: web3.utils.toHex(nonce),
   gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(gasPrice * 1e9),
   gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(gasLimit),
   to: ContractAddress,
   value: '0x00',
   data: functionAbi
 });

 tx.sign(ethereumjs.Buffer.Buffer.from(formatedPrivteKey, "hex"));

 var raw = "0x" + tx.serialize().toString("hex");

 web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw)
  .on('receipt', function(receipt) {
    console.log(receipt);
  }).on("error", console.error);
}
```

Note : Add web3 : [web3 1.0](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/1.0/dist/web3.min.js)

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="web3.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="ethereumjs-wallet-0.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

Init. web3 :

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws"));
```

.user is not adding in whitelist
when i use console of the browser and call the function "sendTransaction" from console :

```
sendTransaction()
undefined
```

after few seconds :

```
web3.min.js:1 connection not open on send()
u.send @ web3.min.js:1
u.send @ web3.min.js:1
u.removeSubscription @ web3.min.js:1
a.unsubscribe @ web3.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ web3.min.js:1
Promise.catch (async)
g @ web3.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ web3.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ web3.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ web3.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ web3.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ web3.min.js:1
connection.onmessage @ web3.min.js:1
web3.min.js:1 Error: Failed to check for transaction receipt:
{}
    at Object._fireError (web3.min.js:1)
    at web3.min.js:1
```

when i check

```
Contract.methods.isAddressWhiteList("0x9DA80947ACf5Fc16299311EdAabc37fF7d201C95").call().then(console.log);
```

it's return false

Comment: Did you check the transaction receipt? It might have failed or being delayed if your gas price is low.

Comment: yes , showing error : 
web3.min.js:1 connection not open on send()
u.send @ web3.min.js:1
u.send @ web3.min.js:1
u.removeSubscription @ web3.min.js:1
a.unsubscribe @ web3.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ web3.min.js:1
Promise.catch (async)
g @ web3.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ web3.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ web3.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ web3.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ web3.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ web3.min.js:1
connection.onmessage @ web3.min.js:1
web3.min.js:1 Error: Failed to check for transaction receipt:
{}
    at Object._fireError (web3.min.js:1)
    at web3.min.js:1

Comment: @Ismael, I updated the question.

Comment: It seems to be an open issue reported in both infura https://github.com/INFURA/infura/issues/95 and web3js https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1255 (and a couple more)

Comment: Yes ! I checked .. What is the other option ?

Comment: I see no other option but wait for it to be fixed, you can try some of the workaround suggested in the bug report.